# When this label is used, can you recycle the carton's cap?

Tags: usa, food

Usually, when recycling, I see cartons with labels saying to "empty and replace cap." However, labels such as the following lack such a notice:

[image: A recycling label that says "Coated Paper: Carton"]

When placing the carton in the recycle container, am I permitted to include the cap, or should I recycle only the carton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legal answer is, if and only if the local authorities or your contract allow it. Recycling may be mandated by local ordinance: check the local ordinance. Or you may have a private contract with a company: check that contract.